# How to INSERT into 1 table and update the count of another

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

My Insert query is :

```
function CreateResult($init_quizz_id,$result_title,$result_image,$result_description) {
$sql = "INSERT  INTO result_quizz(init_quizz_id,result_title
        ,result_image,result_description) 
        VALUES('$init_quizz_id','$result_title','$result_image','$result_description')";



if ( $GLOBALS['conn']->query($sql) === TRUE) {

            echo "Result Added";

     $sql2 = "UPDATE 'init_quizz' SET 'results_count' = 'results_count' +1 WHERE 'quizz_id' = '$init_quizz_id'";

    $GLOBALS['conn']->query($sql2);
 if (!$GLOBALS['conn']->query($sql2)) {
    echo ' NO UPDATE';

 }
}
}
```

Lets say i have init_quizz table with the questions, and another table quizz_results. I want to increase the results_count on every quizz when result is added. My result table is hoilding also an init_quizz_id which is the actual ID of the quizz. 
Im beginner so im looking for any solution to that.
Thanks

edit: fixed the error on the second query( sql2 ) and getting "not updated" msg. Seems like my second query is completely wrong. Any ideas?

Comment: You should use a trigger for this. You can find more information about triggers [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/trigger-syntax.html)

Comment: This is poor normalization. Instead of storing the result count in a separate table, you should just use a query that counts the results in the first table.

Comment: There's no way to do this in a single query, except with a trigger. If you do it in two queries, you should use a transaction to make sure the tables are kept consistent.

Comment: You also have a syntax error in the `UPDATE` query. It should be `SET result_count = result_count + 1`

Comment: Thanks i fixed the error, but still its 0 at my results_count table.

Comment: **WARNING**: This has some severe [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/) because arbitrary data is used inside the query. Whenever possible use **prepared statements**. These are quite straightforward to do in [`mysqli`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) where any user-supplied data is specified with a `?` or `:name` indicator that’s later populated using `bind_param` or `execute` depending on which one you’re using.

Comment: @Barmar thanks i`ll probabbly use count and select from results where they have the id of the quizz , it looks better solution

Answer (score 0):

@barmar was right, i found a better solution for my counter instead of UPDATE, i just returning the affected rows which have quizz_id from my results table.

```
function GetResultsCountByID($quizz_id) {
    global $conn;
     $sql = "SELECT * FROM result_quizz WHERE init_quizz_id = '$quizz_id'";

    $result = $conn->query($sql);
    return  mysqli_affected_rows($conn);
}
```